# Rendering Visualforce field based on Profile Id

Tags: visualforce, rendering

I've created a Visualforce page and I want a record to render as an inputfield for certain profiles. Can someone help me with the Profile Id syntax?

The following works if I remove the following: {!$Profile.Id} = '00ec0000000Htxe'

However, if I add it, it gives me the following error: 'Save error: Syntax error'

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you want to accomplish, and what you have tried so far?

Comment: This is what I have. It works when I remove '{!$Profile.Id} = '00ec0000000Htxe'} '       <apex:inputField value="{!i.Answer_Text__c}" style="width:80%" rendered="{!IF(AND(i.Status__c!='Submitted', i.Question__r.Type__c == 'Text', {!$Profile.Id} = '00ec0000000Htxe'} ), 'true', 'false')}" />

Comment: And what's wrong with that? Please **[edit]** your post with any updates rather than crowding them into the comments section.

Comment: I get the following error: 'Save error: Syntax error'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues:

- You don't need to use merge field within a merge field.

  - This issue is what's causing your expression to break.
- Don't hard-code Ids, use `$Profile.Name` instead.
- You can always simplify `IF(condition, true, false)` to just `condition`.

**Incorrect**

```
rendered="{!AND({!$Profile.Id}='<id_here>', /*other clauses here*/)}"
```

**Correct**

```
rendered="{!AND($Profile.Name='<profile_name_here>', /*other clauses here*/)}"
```

Comment: This is the old-school way of doing it. Today, I'd recommend a [custom permission](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/custom_perms_overview.htm) for additional versatility.

Comment: Yes, that is a great way to whitelist users and preferable to other options in many cases. We have so little context here, it is hard to recommend that route specifically.